# How to access JSDoc types defined inside of a function from outside?

Tags: types, scope, jsdoc

I'm having an initializer function which creates an object with a very complex structure based on configuration parameters. The object's type is determined perfectly by JSDoc and I want to use that type from outside of the function (both in the same file and from outside of it).

Like this:

```js
function init() {
    let obj = createTheObject({ configProp: 'someValue' });

    /**
     * @typedef {typeof obj} MyObject
     */

    // then later I can do
    /**
     * @param {MyObject} obj
     */
    function fn(obj){
        doesSomethingWith(obj.configProp);
    }
}

// but I want to also do
/**
 * @param {MyObject} obj
 */
function fn2(obj){
    doesSomethingElseWith(obj.configProp);
}
// but MyObject type is not recognized so the parameter remains "any" :(
```

This is very much the same question as [How to get types of variables from outside the scope of a functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75051577/how-to-get-types-of-variables-from-outside-the-scope-of-a-functions) (which is for TypeScript) but I'm looking for the solution with JSDoc. I have the feeling that the answer may be the same but still hope that I may have missed something.